# Is it possible to create a Chrome Extension that can execute javascript functions belonging to the page being browsed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Below is my initial attempt. First I created a test webpage:

**- test.html -**

```
<HTML>
<SCRIPT src="script.js"></SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

**- script.js -**

```
function testFunction() {
  console("function successfully run!");
}
```

Then I created a very simple extension to see if I could run testFunction() from the content script:

**- manifest.json -**

```
{
  "name": "Function Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1",
  "description": "An extension to experiment with running the javascript functions of the website being browsed.",
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["cs.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

**- cs.js -**

```
scriptNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
script = scriptNodes[0];
console.log(script.src);
script.testFunction();
```

Here is the console output:

```
file:///C:/.../script.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLScriptElement> has no method 'testFunction'
```

So, is it possible to run a function on a website you are browsing using a Chrome Extension?

Comment: What is your use case?  Are you trying to build a jsfiddle clone?

Comment: If this is meant to be a joke then sorry, I don't get it :p I'm wanting to build an extension which will in some way run the javascript of a website being browsed. Thats all I'm saying!

Comment: a method is not a property of the script tag

Comment: Hi @JuanMendes, I can see that from the console output... I was just having a guess at how it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be impossible.

See [#4658143](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6563062/1800245) and http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

Comment: Ooooooooh. Are you sure? Is there really no way?

Comment: ... sorry, but that's what the official page says. :/

Comment: -1 for saying "impossible". It's certainly possible (marked question as duplicate).

Comment: I said "seems to be" not "it is". Nevermind!

Comment: @naeramarth7 A downvote is an encouragement to improve the answer (downvotes can be retracted). If you don't know how to correct the answer, then a deletion would be most suitable (so that future visitors don't get false information).

Comment: @Rob W I'm not encouraged about the downvote. See, I refered to an already existing answer and the official developer's guide saying, that content scripts "cannot" do this. So the official word "cannot" makes me say, that it "seems impossible" for me in the first place - at least without exploiting.